# QLoggingCategory::setFilterRules usage

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on quite a large project which uses QLoggingCategory in lots of modules.  In main the very first line of code is:

```
    QLoggingCategory::setFilterRules("*.info=false\n");
```

In one of the class cpp files in its own namespace is:

```
    namespace Constants {
        const QLoggingCategory DebugCategory("ModePreviewManager");
        ...
```

I'm trying to get to grips with how to use this to filter out what is currently a huge amount of debug information written to the Application Output.

Can anyone help on how I would use the above to limit the output to just this module?  I've taken at look at the QLoggingCategory online documentation it isn't very clear on how to use it to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setFilterRules sets everything (all categories) information to off, if I change it to . then this turns off all categories and all modes.

I can then enable specific categories with:

```
QLoggingCategory::setFilterRules("*.[<type>]=false\n"
                                 "ModePreviewManager.debug=true");
```

Where [ < type > ] insert "debug,info,warning or critical".